# how to deal with HR response on job offer decision

Tags: interviewing, human-resources

I am recent graduate from my second master program (from an European country). Also have 5 to 6 years of work experience (in an Asian country). My first masters was from America. I have been recently interviewed by a big company in another European country (than my second masters program). This was exactly 10 days ago. This was the only call I have got in last two years! I really answered almost all questions and interviewer mentioned that I should know from the HR in a week's time. So on Monday (5 days ago) I sent a follow up email to which recruiter responded very politely that I am "very interested candidate" for the job, but they have not reached a final decision yet. I am totally desperate to start working and this wait is basically killing me. There is no other interview in pipeline and to be honest the job I have been interviewed is what I am interested in doing given my knowledge and experience.

When, how should I go back to the recruiter on email? I don't want to ruin my only chance. Or should I just sit back and keep waiting?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Workplace SE. Your situation is an understandably frustrating one but not uncommon. In my other comment I've linked to another question which should have some answers that are useful to you. Hope you get a good result!

Comment: @motosubatsu: Thank you for your response. Yes let me go though the link that you shared earlier. Hope it will help me getting back to the HR in a positive way.